# Regardin feedback panel

Tags: java, wicket

I have "ok" and "cancel" button. I used feedback panel. If I select cancel button, date time, then I'm still getting a feedback messages.

Please could you help me out with this?

Comment: You'll need to add some code to your question to give people a better idea of what you are having trouble with.

Comment: 1. please improve the grammar, 2. use the correct tags, 3. give a code snippet: show what you have tried and what didn't work as expected. 4. specify the language and libraries you use

Comment: This question is indeed vaguely phrased and could use improvement ther, but I understood the question sufficiently to answer.  I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

In the creation of your cancel button, you want something resembling

```
    Button cancel = new CancelButton();
    cancel.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
```

This will cause the form handling to bypass the form processing done on a normal submit, including validation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the cancel button is still in your code as a Button attached to the form. Any button in a wicket form will try and validate the input. Buttons shouldn't be used for canceling actions anyway. Use a link (this will not validate the form) and style it like a button if you wish.